# How to Write/Read ArrayList<Marker> into file

Tags: android, google-maps, arraylist, google-maps-android-api-2, marker

I need to write/read an `ArrayList<Marker>` to a file.
Here is what I did so far:

**Save List:**

```
private void saveToFile(ArrayList<Marker> arrayList) {
        try {
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = openFileOutput("test.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
            out.writeObject(arrayList);
            out.close();
            fileOutputStream.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
```

**Load List**

```
private ArrayList<Marker> loadFromFile() {
        ArrayList<Marker> savedArrayList = null;

        try {
            FileInputStream inputStream = openFileInput("test.txt");
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);
            savedArrayList = (ArrayList<Marker>) in.readObject();
            in.close();
            inputStream.close();

        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return savedArrayList;
    }
```

When I run the code I'm getting `ClassNotFoundException`.
The issue is that I need to store the whole `ArrayList<Marker>` as object.
I have found a solution that it separates the `Marker` into lat/long and write it to the text file as numbers, but it is not suitable for me.
I understand that the `Marker` Class is not `Serializable`, but how then it can be saved as an whole object?

Comment: Looks like using a SQLite database would be a better option.

Comment: @DanielNugent Isn't that meaning that I will have to separate `Marker` into properties?
Lat/Long and so on?